# Which programming language is simplest to use (for the user) as an integrated scripting language?

Tags: .net, user-interface, scripting, scripting-language

I'm writing a multiple choice test program for teachers. The formula for the marks is:

```
(points awarded) / (maximum score) * 5 + 1.
```

This gives a mark in the range [1,6].

Now I want to add a scripting language, with which a teacher can define the formula for the mark him/herself.

Assuming the teacher is a person that doesn't know a lot about programming, which programming language would be the best choice to integrate as scripting language (from the standpoint of simplicity of use)?

Some of the possible choices are:

- JavaScript
- Python
- Lua
- VB.NET
- C#
- Ruby
- Vala

My natural tendency would be towards JavaScript or Python. However, I am a bit wary as those 2 languages are case-sensitive programming languages.

The only case-insensitive option I am aware of would be VB.NET. Are there any other good choices?

Comment: There's always AppleScript. Anyone written a .NET parser for that yet? :-)

Comment: This question might be a little subjective... is there any way "simplest" could be narrowed down a bit?

Comment: See also: [Scripting language for embedding into C#/.NET applications?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/462311), [What is the best scripting language to embed in a C# desktop application?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/137933), [Scripting Language in a Sandbox for a C#/.NET Application](http://stackoverflow.com/q/564357), [.net scripting languages](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3997911),

Comment: This never works. The user doesn't understand or forget how to do it, so you get a phone call. Then you curse yourself for inventing yet another scripting dialect and wish you'd just hardcoded and parameterized it.

Comment: @CodeCaster: You confirm my worst fears ;)

Comment: What about [Ook!](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Ook!)? Even monkeys are able to understand it ^^

Comment: Do you *need* a scripting language, or do you just need a way for a user to define a formula?

Comment: https://github.com/patriksvensson/arithmetica

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need a whole programming language to calculate the mark?

Simply use your programming language of choice to create a nice interface where the teachers have some flexibility.

You could for example have a simple input and allow the teachers to enter in some variable you've already defined, maybe $points and $max_score as well as a few basic math operators (*/-+) and then you can read the input and interpret it.

Alternatively you could use drop downs and other control to have a finer level of control, the options here are really only limited by your imagination.

Comment: Yeah, this is probably the best way to solve the problem. Perhaps [something like Apple does for date/time formats](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PdqFc.jpg), which makes a complex task rather simple and intuitive.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. So is this answer what you were after?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't the person who asked the question. :-)

Comment: haha. sorry Cody. My bad for trying to multi-task.